# Give one possible input for a desired output value in R

Tags: r, function, optimization, statistics, linear-algebra

Suppose my function `d` below can output the same answer for a different combination of its two input values.

For example, to output `0.8164966`, one can input `d(2, 12)` or similarly `d(1, 3)` and many more combinations of the two input values.

**Question** Is there a way to get **just one possible** pair of input values IF I provide the desired output `d`?

For example, if I desire to have a `d = 0.8164966`, can R give me just `1 and 3` as one pair of possible input values that lead to a `d = 0.8164966`?

**NOTE:**  I'm asking how to solve for ***only one pair of possible (there are many) input values*** given any `d` (the output).

```
d <- function(mean_dif, Vmax) mean_dif/sqrt(Vmax/2)

d(2, 12)  # 0.8164966
d(1, 3)   # 0.8164966
```

Comment: Are you asking for a solution for just `d`, or for any function of two inputs?

Comment: Is `d` as shown above, or could it be some other function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this to work for a general `d`, you need to give the solver a hint.  For example, is there guaranteed to be a solution with the first argument equal to 1?  What's the range of possible values for the second argument if the first is 1?

With the `d` you give, the answers are "yes, it's guaranteed", and an explicit solution is `Vmax = 2/d^2`, i.e.

```
inv_d <- function(d) {
   c(mean_dif = 1, Vmax = 2/d^2)
}
```

and you get

```
inv_d(pi)
# mean_dif      Vmax 
# 1.0000000 0.2026424
```

Now, if you didn't know that solution for `Vmax`, you could try using `uniroot`:

```
inv_d <- function(dval) {
  Vmax <- uniroot(function(Vmax) d(1, Vmax) - dval, c(0, 10/dval^2))$root
  c(mean_dif = 1, Vmax = Vmax)
}

inv_d(pi)
# mean_dif      Vmax 
# 1.0000000 0.2026534
```

In this case the solution is a bit less accurate.

If you can't get the interval or the guarantee, then in general there's no solution, but you might be able to try a bunch of different guesses and sometimes get lucky.

Comment: Thanks, upvoted, `Vmax` should be larger than "0", does that help?

Answer (score 1):

This boils down to converting a decimal to a rational number. One way to do this is using `MASS::fractions`. That means we can write your inverse function like this:

```r
inv_d <- function(d) {
  ratio <- MASS::fractions(d^2/2)
  result <- as.numeric(strsplit(attr(ratio, "fracs"), "/")[[1]])
  result[1] <- result[1]^2
  setNames(result, c("mean_dif", "Vmax"))
}
```

So you can do:

```r
inv_d(d(2, 12))
#> mean_dif     Vmax 
#>        1        3 

inv_d(d(1, 3))
#> mean_dif     Vmax 
#>        1        3 

inv_d(d(5, 100))
#> mean_dif     Vmax 
#>        1        4
```

Comment: It seems your solution breaks at times for example try: `inv_d(pi)` then use its output in `d()`!

Comment: @morouzian pi is an irrational number. There are no two integers for which `d` could ever output pi. That's not the function's fault, that's just how the universe is!

Comment: I see, but at the end, I used `inv_d <- function(d) {
  c(mean_dif = 1, Vmax = 2/d^2)
}` which as far as I understand doesn't have any exception.

Comment: @morouzian of course. This is the trivial rearrangement of your original function; I assumed you knew this already, and were looking for a way to transform this into two integers.

Comment: I meant I came to the conclusion that `inv_d <- function(d) {   c(mean_dif = 1, Vmax = 2/d^2) }` is just fine.

Comment: @AllanCameron:  The mathematical constant is irrational, but `pi` in R is rational, just like every other number that R can represent.

Comment: @user2554330 I know what you mean: the double precision floating point number that R uses to represent pi could of course be represented by a pair of large 64-bit integers. That wasn't really the point I was making though; I meant that pi (either actual pi or R pi) can't be simplified to the ratio of two small integers by the use of the `fraction` function in `MASS` the way that say `0.333333` is converted to `1/3`. I'm sorry that I didn't make this clearer..